# How do most implementations of SHA-256 work?

Tags: sha-256

Why is it that most implementations define an `sha256_init`, `sha256_update`, and `sha256_final` function that each operates on a `SHA256_CTX` object? The specification only mentions returning an almost unique hash for any given string of bits of any given length.

- What is the reason to have these 3 functions instead of just a standalone function that returns an output hash for an input bitstring?
- What exactly does CTX stand for?

Comment: CTX is more implementation specific. Contexts are often used in non-object oriented programming languages to keep state. A similar construction including a context is used for symmetric encryption modes.

Comment: CTX is a programming term, not necessarily a cryptographic one.

Comment: mostly dupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52136/cryptographic-hasing-functions-init-update-final

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the reason to have these 3 functions instead of just a standalone function that returns an output hash for an input bitstring?

This allows to compute the hash of a piece of information that is made available by segments, rather than as a single memory block. This comes handy in many situations, including

- When the data is too large to fit memory (e.g. hash of a large file)
- When the data to hash is the content of many network packets (the alternative would require a memory buffer as large as the sum of the length of the packets, and a copy of each packet into that, which is time consuming and kills the cache).
- When it's desired to perform activities at time intervals smaller than the duration of the whole hash, in a single-thread context. We break the data into pieces, and perform the activity between the hash of individual pieces.
- When several hashes must be computed concurrently (e.g. multiple users of a server with less threads than users).

> What exactly does CTX stand for?

Context. It holds the current state of the hash being computed, typically the 32 bytes of the current chaining value, a number (typically at most 64) of messages bytes not hashed yet, and the length of the data so far (typically on 8 bytes). A typical SHA-256 context is thus 104 bytes, or slightly more.